# Web SQL Database + Javascript loop

Tags: javascript, sql, html, loops, web-sql

I'm trying to figure this out but can't seem to on my own...

I'm playing with Web SQL DBs and I can't get a loop to work properly with it.

I use:

```
for (var i=0; i<=numberofArticles-1; i++){  
    db.transaction(function (tx) {  
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LOGS (articleID) VALUES (?)',  [i]);
  });
 };
```

And I get only 5's.. I don't get the incremental i values.

Can anyone suggestion what I'm doing wrong and what I should be thinking about?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the function is asynchronous, and that by the time `tx.executeSql` fires, the loop have finished looping and `i` has been changed several times.

You can solve this with a closure.

```
for (var i=0; i<=numberofArticles-1; i++){ 
    function (value) { 
        db.transaction(function (tx) {  
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LOGS (articleID) VALUES (?)',  [value]);
      });
    }(i); // <-- CALL the function
 };
```

Comment: @David Dorward
Could you please explain a little the sintax (the javascript not the websql)? Especially the line " }(i); // <-- CALL the function". I mean, i could just copy the code, but i'd like to fully understand it.

Comment: You call a function by sticking `(any args)` on the end of it. `function (){}()` is just like `function foo() {}; foo();` except it doesn't keep `foo` around for later use.

Comment: (and since variables are local to a specific function call, having a new function call each time around the loop makes new local variables)

Comment: one last thing, shouldn't the argument for the insert be "[value]" instead of "[i]"?

Comment: That is incorrect. The argument for the function should be i, but the argument for the insert should be value - the code as written works only by coincidence

Answer (score 11):

Do it the other way around:

```
<script>
    numberofArticles = 5;
    db = openDatabase("websql", "0.1", "web-sql testing", 10000);
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LOGS (id unique, articleID int)');
    });
    db.transaction(function (tx) {  
        for (var i=0; i<=numberofArticles-1; i++){  
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LOGS (articleID) VALUES (?)',  [i]);
        };
    });
</script>
```

And the alternative, the proper way with the loop outside which is unnecessary in this case

```
    for (var i=0; i<=numberofArticles-1; i++){  
      (function(i) {
        db.transaction(function (tx) {  
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LOGS (articleID) VALUES (?)',  [i]);
        });
      })(i);
    };
```