# WebSQL: INSERT of many rows / transactions

Tags: database, html, transactions, web-sql

I have problem with asynchronous call of INSERT in db.transaction when parsing large CSV.

**Problem #1:**

```
while(...parse CSV...) {
db.transaction{
...tx.executeSql(INSERT...
}
}
```

...it will enter the last row X times (X ... number of rows in CSV)

**Problem #2:**

```
db.transaction{
while(...parse CSV...) {
...tx.executeSql(INSERT...
}
}
```

...it will reach some limit and will not insert anything (if I don't use while, but for like <10, it works, but this limit is quite small).

It is similar to this question: [Web SQL Database + Javascript loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825455/web-sql-database-javascript-loop), but the recursion will not help here.

Thanks!

Comment: Example #1 won't work because you're creating multiple transactions asynchronously within a while loop, which is bad. Example #2 is better, because you're doing 1 transaction instead of many, and looping within the single transaction. However, please add actual code for example #2 so we can try and see why a limit is being imposed :)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a sollution. It is better to divide these two things - parse CSV and then call some function like saveOneRow(column1, column2...) with transaction in this function.