# Only the last run in a for loop in Javascript works

Tags: javascript, html, web-sql

Here is a for loop written by Javascript. It is trying to apply queries for websql.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    db.transaction(function (tx){
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO ProjSetsT (ProjID) VALUES (?);', [i]);
    });
}
```

The attempt is obvious, I tried to add values "0, 1, 2, ... 9" into column ProjID in table ProjSetsT. It does not work. I only got the last element, i.e. "9" inserted, but not the first  eight numbers.

Is there any syntax mistakes?

Comment: Syntax mistakes would prevent it from running outright... WebSQL is an asynchronous API, you can't expect it to catch the right values this way. See [Web SQL Database + Javascript loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825455/web-sql-database-javascript-loop). Also, running multiple queries in one transaction is faster and actually guarantees the insertion order. Running each one in a separate transaction is a slow free-for-all with random ordering.

Comment: Why not make one query? Where the value binded is a string built from the values in the for loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `db.transaction` might run asynchronously so that might be messing it up for you. Have you tried to move your for loop inside the transaction?

```
db.transaction(function (tx){
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO ProjSetsT (ProjID) VALUES (?);', [i]);
    }
});
```

Comment: You are right. And I think this is the most straight forward method to do it though other people's advices all work. That's why I put yours as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Every function you pass as an argument shares the same reference to `i`, so every new function object's `i` value gets incremented. given the async context, `i` will have reached its max size before the first function you create inside the loop gets called

You can fix it using a closure:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    db.transaction((function(privateI)
    {//privateI is unique for every function object
        return function (tx)
        {
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO ProjSetsT (ProjID) VALUES (?);', [privateI]);
        };
    })(i));//pass current value here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several functions referencing the same `i` variable, which ends up as `10`.

You need a new varible scope for each function.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    db.transaction(makeHandler(i));
}

function makeHandler(j) {
    return function (tx){
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO ProjSetsT (ProjID) VALUES (?);', [j]);
    };
}
```

Now `i` is passed to `makeHandler`, which receives it as `j`.

Every time `makeHandler` is called, it returns a function that references its own local `j` varaible.