# transaction inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, transactions, web-sql

I want to run a transaction inside a for loop. My code is :-

```
 for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
      // some code

      alert('before transaction');

      var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Pin Point", 200000);
      db.transaction(fetchSubList, errorLists);  

      alert('after transaction');
  }


 function fetchSubList(tx) {  
    tx.executeSql('some QUERY', [], fetchSubListSuccess, errorLists);
  }


function fetchSubListSuccess(tx, results) {
  alert("fetchSubListSuccess()...");

  // some code
}
```

But the problem is that after the alert (before transaction) i directly get alert (after transaction) and only when the for loop ends then the transaction start....

I followed the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825455/web-sql-database-javascript-loop) link to solve but still i'm not able to figure it out....

Comment: It asyncronous - what else did you expect?

Comment: I don't think you should open many databases in the same for-loop

Comment: `db.transaction` takes a `successCallback` parameter, do the `after transaction` alert in there.

Comment: @Bergi yes i know its async... but how can i achieve this (i mean i want it to work as synchronous)

Comment: @Barmar The 2 alerts keeps on coming one after the other based on the number of times the loop is running... But only after the loop has ended then the fetchSubList() function is called....

Comment: You can't - you will need to use callbacks

Comment: You could use the `DatabaseSync` API to get synchronous operations.

Comment: @Barmar do u mean var db = window.openDatabaseSync("Database", "1.0", "Pin Point", 200000); ..... well this gives me an error at console

Comment: @Bergi callbacks.... can u explain how exactly can i use callbacks based on my requirements...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do it... We need to refactor the code so that code looks like this :-

```
    db.transaction(function(tx) 
    {

      // some value
      var loop_limit = 10

      for(var i=0; i<loop_limit;i++ ){ // ITERATE HERE
        tx.executeSql(Statement, [],Sucess, error);
      }

    });
```