# Phonegap Storage Database size limit

Tags: android, sql, cordova

Phonegap uses this code:

```
var dbShell = window.openDatabase(name, version, display_name, size);
```

The documentation states that this creates a  **SQL Lite Database**. Now I'm not sure if the fourth parameter (size) is the EstimatedSize or the limit size?

If ever, what would be the limit size of the SQL Lite database?

Answer (score 0):

It is the size of the database so -unless I missed a trap- the limit size.

["The size of the database in bytes."](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#size)

Comment: so if it was the limit size, then what happens if you exceed it? or is there a way to set it do limitless (technically size increases as long as there is an available storage). Thanks

Comment: [This guy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15903329/phonegap-storage?rq=1) got an undefined sql error because of a size too small. I don't think you can have a dynamic database.