# Adding values dynamically to the table in Web SQL database using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web-sql

I am fetching values from web service. And I have to insert those values into the table in Web SQL database.

I have 4 records. I have inserted the following code into the loop, but only the last record is added in database and not the first 3 records.

```
for(var t=0;t<main_category.length;t++){
        db.transaction(function(tx){
            var insertStatement="INSERT INTO main_menu(catId,catName,catImage) VALUES(?,?,?)";
            tx.executeSql(insertStatement, [menu_id, menu_name, menu_img]);
            console.log("values inserted "+ t);
        });
}
```

I tried many solutions, following link has one of them,

[Web SQL Database + Javascript loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825455/web-sql-database-javascript-loop)

But, it did not work. Please suggest me how can I populate the table with dynamic values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
for(var t = 0; t < main_category.length; t++){
        (function(i) {
            var item = main_category[i];
            var menu_id = item.id, menu_name = item.name, menu_img = item.img;
            db.transaction(function(tx) {
                var insertStatement="INSERT INTO main_menu(catId,catName,catImage) VALUES(?,?,?)";
                tx.executeSql(insertStatement, [menu_id, menu_name, menu_img]);
                console.log("values inserted "+ i);
            });
        })(t);
}
```

result:

[image]

Comment: but the values are not getting inserted in the table in database.

Comment: i am working this code.. http://puu.sh/a1Lds/d72bb5e8d3.png , so which browser are you using?

Comment: Aah! made slight changes, its working just the catNames and catImages are having issues, all values are getting inserted there in first row then decrement by 1 in second row and so on.