# WebSQL loop array onComplete Handler

Tags: javascript, web-sql

I want to build up on an existing solution to find out when all elements in an array have been inserted successfully.

[Web SQL Database + Javascript loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825455/web-sql-database-javascript-loop)

```
insert: function(configurationVOs) {
    var self = this;

    this.database.transaction(function(transaction){
        var total = 0;
        for(var i=0; i<configurationVOs.length; i++) {
            (function(configurationVO) {
                var params = [configurationVO.id, configurationVO.key, configurationVO.value, configurationVO.type];
                transaction.executeSql(self.configurationInsertSQL, params, self.insertComplete, self.insertError);
            })(configurationVOs[i]);
        }
    });
},
```

if someone can provide an elegant self-contained solution within this for loop/function that can do a single callback upon success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My attempt, please edit/suggest for any improvements.

```
insert: function(configurationVOs) {
        var self = this;
        this.database.transaction(function(transaction){
            var total = 0;
            for(var i=0; i<configurationVOs.length; i++) {
                (function() {
                    var params = [configurationVOs[i].id, configurationVOs[i].key, configurationVOs[i].value, configurationVOs[i].type];
                    transaction.executeSql(self.configurationInsertSQL, params, function(transaction, resultSet){
                        if(++total == configurationVOs.length) {
                            self.insertComplete();
                        }
                    }, self.insertError);
                })();
            }
        });
    },
```